# Define several JuMP variables names in loop based on iteration

Tags: julia, julia-jump

A bit new to julia, and JuMP. I wanted to define variables in a loop i.e x_i for some loop index i. For example.

```
for i=1:10
@variable(m, x_i[1:100], bin)

end
```

and then reference x_i as needed, just as I would normally (without a loop) use x_1 if I hard coded it in constraints, objective etc. Effectively here, I would like to not have to hardcode.

From the documentation:

```
@variable(model, expr, args..., kw_args...)
```

Looks like you pass an expression, but its not clear how I would do this/if it is possible. Also it would be useful to know if I can do this, what the syntax is to reference the x_i created in the loop appropiatley in constraints, objectives, etc.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options:

```
@variable(m, x[i=1:10, 1:100], Bin)

x[1, 99]
```

```
x = [@variable(m, [1:100], Bin) for i in 1:10]

x[1][99]
```

But in no case can you dynamically create a binding like `x_i`.

Comment: Hey Oscar, thanks for the quick reply. I guess the user case I was interested in further was x_i would be either real, integer, or binary vectors. I.e lets say if i=1 those variables are real, if i=2 those are integer, etc. Is there the ability to build in this logic?

Comment: Use the keyword arguments: `@variable(m, [1:100], integer = i > 1)`